# Duration of insurance for Italy visa

Tags: italy, insurance

The checklist for Italy visa from Mumbai states the following regarding travel insurance:

"Covering travel period with coverage of Euros 30000 inclusive of a repatriation clause. Minimum 10 days insurance is mandatory from the travel date."

I wish to travel Italy from 18-29'October. So, should I take insurance for the travel period of 12days i.e. from 18-29'October or for 22days (with additional 10days from the return travel date). In fact I have already purchased insurance for 14days.

Answer (score 3):

Schengen Visa Code [requires the following](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/ALL/?uri=CELEX:32009R0810):

> Article 10. General rules for lodging an application
>
> ...
>
> (g) where applicable, produce proof of possession of adequate and
>   valid travel medical insurance in accordance with Article 15.
>
> Article 15. Travel medical insurance
>
> ...
>
> 3. The insurance shall be valid throughout the territory of the Member States **and cover the entire period of the person’s intended
>      stay or transit**. The minimum coverage shall be EUR 30 000.

Thus you should be good only covering your travel dates. There is no need to keep it longer, and travel insurance is usually not valid in your home country anyway.

There is also no "minimum ten days" rule in the Schengen Visa Code.

Comment: Checked with VFS, they confirmed that insurance must be for a minimum period of 10days if the travel duration is less than 10days. For visit duration of more than 10days, the insurance must cover the entire duration.